# Showing that a domain is not simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

We have that $\Omega = U/[-1/2 ,1/2]$, where $U$ is the closed unit disk in the complex plane, and have to show that it is not simply connected. Does it suffice to say that $1\over z$ is analytic on $\Omega$ and that $\int_C {1\over z}dz$ where $C$ is the circle with radius $2/3$ is $2\pi$ and so it's not simply connected?

Comment: Yes, it suffices. (But do you know why)?

Comment: Cauchy's Theorem? Saying the integral is the same over paths that are homotopic, and therefore this path is not homotopic to a constant path (null homotopic)?

Comment: Yes, perfect! ${}{}$